# UseParams not picking value properly

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a URL like this

```
http://localhost:3000/connectionservice#access_token=asdadas2asdadaasdadagxdasdadadaq&scope=&state=6as4318asdadadadasc6aas37a&token_type=bearer
```

I'm trying to pick access_token and state from this like this...it's not working

```
  import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

   const { state, access_token } = useParams();
```

Comment: Can you show where you're getting the params, and how you are passing it to the props?

Comment: @JairoPy I'm useParams while copy pasting, i copied the wrong code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they have the search params after the hash of the URL.

You can use the built-in URL and URLSearchParams API like this. We'll get the hash (the part after `#`) and then get the parameters individually.

```js
const url = new URL("http://localhost:3000/connectionservice#access_token=asdadas2asdadaasdadagxdasdadadaq&scope=&state=6as4318asdadadadasc6aas37a&token_type=bearer");

const params = new URLSearchParams(url.hash.slice(1));

console.log("state:", params.get("state"));
console.log("access_token:", params.get("access_token"));
```